# Maven prevent build if there is uncommitted changes

Tags: java, git, maven

Is there any way to check if there is not committed files or untracked files in git repo and prevent maven build?

I mean if I run

```
mvn install
```

And install should fail with warning that there is something to commit.

I need this because I want to know hash of commit which corresponds to some builded **.war** file. Sometimes I forgot to commit changes and build **.war** file, and as a result I can't reproduce this build exactly as it was.

Comment: You probably want to use something like Jenkins.  You can [read about it here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511).

Comment: configure your maven build to get the appropriate informations from git via buildnumber-maven-plugin and put those information into MANIFEST.MF file. Furthermore never create releases or SNAPSHOT from local workplace. Let a CI server do such a job.

Answer (score 4):

Generally these kinds of problems are resolved by *never* building releases out of developer workstations.

One way to avoid that is to have a single machine where the git repository is pulled into a clean directory, and the build is launched from there.  Then you always use the "mainline build" for your testing and deployment.

Jenkins is an automated tool that drives clean builds as described above.  There are other tools available, but Jenkins is the most popular.

The best way to know if you have everything committed is to run a `git status` and read the response.  However, even with that understanding, it is very easy to forget to push your commit into the origin, and when you do push it, there is also a chance that you merged commits.  In short, you might have to just take more care in your process, instead of relying on tools to take care for you.

Comment: Jenkins can poll your repository on a regular basis or you can configure your main repository to trigger a new build after each commit.  The trigger approach allows for almost instant builds.

Answer (score 2):

One can use a [git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to accomplish this; I would use something like a [jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) or [hudson](https://hudson-ci.org) to accomplish this, but since you asked about using git, the hook should look like:

```
# pre-commit
git diff || true
```

Mark it as executable and you should be golden.

Comment: A hook is unfortunately not cloned to client machine which makes this an unconvinient solution.

Comment: @khmarbaise OP just wanted a solution for his own use.

Comment: I was wondering if there any maven plugin for this, I understand that I can do it using some bash script or git-hook but it looks strange

Comment: @c0rp: There is a plugin for that, Maven SCM plugin. Just like "git diff", it only works for modified but not for untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

For modified (but not for untracked) files, Maven SCM plugin can help you, specifically [scm:check-local-modification](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/check-local-modification-mojo.html)

Add this to the plugins section:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>check-local-modification</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>compile</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Chose the phase carefully to define where you want the build to stop if there are local modifications. The above example would prevent any compilation. If you want to be able to compile the modified code, consider setting the phase to `package`. That way, you would be able to compile and unit test the modified code, but not to package it to a jar file.